# Gltf wrong rotations

Tags: animation, serialization, rust, graphics, gltf

I have a gltf asset I have verified in multiple places. The asset is correct.

I am trying to load this asset into a custom engine I am making. If I load all animation information, except rotations I get this:

[image]

Which is correct.

If instead of loading the animation rotations I load the rotation of the target node the animation is targeting, i.e. this:

`gltf.nodes[target_node].rotation.quaternion();`

Instead of:

`gltf.data_from_accessor::<Quatf>(sampler.output).unwrap()`

I get this:
[image]

i.e. the same thing.

But if I try loading the data from the accessor I get this abomination:
[image]

I am not sure what to test. As mentioned I know the data itself is fine, so it must be the code. But it's not that the target node order is incorrect, I know for a fact that I do have the correct node-animation mapping.

This is how I am loading the gltf data:

```rust
  let animation = &gltf.animations[animation_id];
    let channel = &animation.channels[channel_id];
    let sampler = &animation.samplers[channel.sampler];

    match channel.target.path
    {
        ChannelPath::ROTATION => {
            debug_assert!(self.rotations.len() == 0);
            for rot in gltf.data_from_accessor::<Quatf>(sampler.output).unwrap()
            {
                self.rotations.push(*rot);
            }

            for time in gltf.data_from_accessor::<f32>(sampler.input).unwrap()
            {
                self.rotation_times.push(*time);
            }
 // ......
}
```

I have a different gltf asset that I am loading with rotations, and that one is fine:

[image]

The animation plays just as expected.

So I have two assets, both are fine according to gltf validators, one goes through the pipeline just fine, the other gets degenerate. I don't understand how rotations can cause this problem :\

I have checked that all quaternion data has norm of 1, which it does, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone runs into something like this. The issue was a byte alignment problem.

The asset that loaded properly specifies its joints as bytes. The other asset as unsigned shorts. The code was assuming the data was always in byte format and thus was not properly initializing the joint vectors of the mesh.